# My program is using an invalid compiler, how do I find the right compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

When I try to build and run my program I get this error message:

> "First Project": The compiler's setup (GNU GCC Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
>   Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! (Do you have a compiler installed?)
>   Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.
>   Skipping...
>   Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
>
> Target uses an invalid compiler; run aborted

I tried to fix this issue on my own by going to Settings->Compiler->Toolchain executables-> and clicking the "Auto-detect" button-> and clicking "OK", but when I did that a window popped up saying

> Enviromental Error
>
> Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for GNU GCC Compiler

I apologize if this question had been asked before, but when I researched this problem, most people fixed it by simply hitting "Auto-detect" and that didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you install a compiler, specifically the GNU GCC compiler?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I don't remember installing a specific compiler, I only installed codeblocks. My OS is Windows 8.1

Comment: Hmm, IIRC CodeBlocks used to come along with a GCC installation.  Anyway installing MinGW as mentioned above should fix this.

Comment: @melak47 I've never had success getting codeblocks to work with mingw-w64 (64-bit).  Have you?

Comment: what's codeblocks? :S

Comment: @melak47 Just yet another IDE.

Answer (score 6):

You probably installed the first executable listed on [this](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) page (I may be speaking from experience).  My advice would be to reinstall using one of the other two executables:

```
codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe
codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe
```

The first executable *only* installs Codeblocks, while the other two include compilers.

Alternatively, you *could* install a compiler yourself, but I've found the process of getting it to work with Codeblocks can be harrowing on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

the first author's answer is correct and I fix this problem with his answer.

==,you can change your choice of Download the binary release to such as
codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe or else,but don't choose the first setup.exe in [this page](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26).

Comment: Does your answer simply recommend a newer release?

Comment: Oh,sorry,i am a new comer here.Sometimes maybe I am not a expert to explain the reason why it doesn't work,but since I have come across the similar problem before.I try my best to give a effective method in my opinion.